java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError com.strandgenomics.cube.framework.ani.SharedProgressMonitorModel.createNativeSharedObject()J
During performing Quantification in java tool NGS it is throwing the UnsatisfiedLinkError. Please find the entrire stack trace.
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.strandgenomics.cube.framework.ani.SharedProgressMonitorModel.createNativeSharedObject()J
    at com.strandgenomics.cube.framework.ani.SharedProgressMonitorModel.createNativeSharedObject(Native Method) ~[rep/:na]
    at com.strandgenomics.cube.framework.sharedobject.SharedObject.<init>(SharedObject.java:17) ~[rep/:na]
    at com.strandgenomics.cube.framework.ani.SharedProgressMonitorModel.<init>(SharedProgressMonitorModel.java:27) ~[rep/:na]
    at com.strandgenomics.cube.framework.ani.NativeAlgorithm.execute(NativeAlgorithm.java:22) ~[rep/:na]
    at com.strandgenomics.spring.stat.QuantileNormAlgorithm.execute(QuantileNormAlgorithm.java:39) ~[spring-stat-3.9.jar:na]
    at com.strandgenomics.spring.stat.NormalizationAlgorithm.execute(NormalizationAlgorithm.java:30) ~[spring-stat-3.9.jar:na]
    at com.strandgenomics.ngs.rnaseq.mrna.expression.QuantileNormalizeWithMV.normalize(QuantileNormalizeWithMV.java:53) ~[rep/:na]
    at com.strandgenomics.ngs.rnaseq.mrna.expression.QuantileNormalizeWithMV.getNormalizedDataset(QuantileNormalizeWithMV.java:35) ~[rep/:na]
    at com.strandgenomics.ngs.rnaseq.mrna.expression.NormalizeAndBaseline.<init>(NormalizeAndBaseline.java:69) ~[rep/:na]
    at com.strandgenomics.ngs.rnaseq.mrna.expression.GeneQuantificationOperations.createNormalizedDataset(GeneQuantificationOperations.java:203) ~[rep/:na]
    at com.strandgenomics.ngs.rnaseq.smallrna.quantification.SmallRNAQuantification.getNormalizedDatasets(SmallRNAQuantification.java:239) ~[rep/:na]
    at com.strandgenomics.ngs.rnaseq.smallrna.quantification.SmallRNAQuantification.getSmallRNAQuantificationNode(SmallRNAQuantification.java:213) ~[rep/:na]
    at com.strandgenomics.ngs.rnaseq.smallrna.quantification.SmallRNAQuantification.run(SmallRNAQuantification.java:158) ~[rep/:na]
    at com.strandgenomics.ngs.rnaseq.smallrna.quantification.SmallRNAQuantificationJob.doRun(SmallRNAQuantificationJob.java:117) ~[rep/:na]
    at com.strandgenomics.cube.pipeline.job.AbstractJob.run(AbstractJob.java:466) ~[cube-pipeline-2.1.jar:na]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
16-04-24 11:06:35.619 [pool-25-thread-1] [VitalStatsMonitor] INFO  VITAL_STATS PROCESS cpu-load=0.02, free-mem=15.08GB, #threads=29, #classes=12786
16-04-24 11:06:35.620 [pool-25-thread-1] [VitalStatsMonitor] INFO  VITAL_STATS SYSTEM cpu-load=8.29, #open-fd=575, free-swap=1.74GB, total-swap=2.00GB
16-04-24 11:06:35.620 [pool-25-thread-1] [VitalStatsMonitor] INFO  VITAL_STATS DISK free-space=252.60GB
16-04-24 11:06:35.620 [pool-25-thread-1] [ROOT] INFO  MST: } Finish: Job: Failed: Run Quantification
16-04-24 11:06:35.620 [pool-25-thread-1] [SmallRNAQuantificationJob] INFO  ---------------------------- Finished executing job ----------------------------
16-04-24 11:06:35.620 [pool-25-thread-1] [SmallRNAQuantificationJob] INFO  Job ID = =1713242315827=JAVA=1406318141
16-04-24 11:06:35.620 [pool-25-thread-1] [SmallRNAQuantificationJob] INFO  Job Name = Run Quantification
16-04-24 11:06:35.620 [pool-25-thread-1] [SmallRNAQuantificationJob] INFO  Job Type = Analysis

I have tried adding the java lib path in the vm options of intellij incase if it is not able to find or load the ani library but that doesn't help.Please provide suggestions. Thank you
-DorderID=FLOATING_LICENSE
-Djavavm=../../../pkg/tools/jdk/1.8.0/jre
**-Djava.library.path=../../../pkg/tools/java/1.8/lib**
-DproductVersion=2.0
-DproductName=NGS
-Dtmp.dir=app/tmp
-Ddata.dir=app/Data


Nothing to do with java/1.8/lib. You need to load the JNI shared library for com.strandgenomics.cube.framework.ani, wherever it is and whatever it is called.

This is a commercial product? Contact their support.
